# How to properly reward player with Admob rewarded video in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AdManager : MonoBehaviour {

RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo;

static InterstitialAd interstitial;

string VideoID = "ca-app-pub-3888784411212422/2850896103";
string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3888784411212422/4158795262";

public static AdManager Instance;
void Start ()
{
    Instance = this;
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    RequestRewardBasedVideo();
    RequestInterstitial();
}

public void RequestRewardBasedVideo()
{       
    rewardBasedVideo = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;
    rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().Build(), adUnitId);
}

public void RequestInterstitial()
{
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(VideoID);
    interstitial.LoadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().Build());
}
public void ShowAd()
{
    if(rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded())
    {
        rewardBasedVideo.Show();
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
    }
}
public static void ShowInter()
{
    showInterstitial(interstitial);
}


private void showAdd(RewardBasedVideoAd r)
{
    if (r.IsLoaded())
    {
        //Subscribe to Ad event
        r.Show();
        r.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
    }
}

public void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward args)
{

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("coin", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coin") + 200);
    GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Coin").GetComponent<Text>().text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coin").ToString();
    GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Double").GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;

    Debug.Log("Pref: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coin"));
}

static void showInterstitial(InterstitialAd i)
{
    if (i.IsLoaded())
    {
        i.Show();
    }
}
}
```

I am rewarding players with 200 coins, but somehow every time i get reward increased by 200. First time when player get rewarded he gets 200, next time he gets 400, next time 600 etc. I have tried to change code in many ways but no positive result.

Method that is called upon button click is ShowAd(). Every time when panel with button thats calls the method is shown i call RequestRewardBasedVideo().

Comment: Why there is 2 function ShowAd() and showAdd() ? Is one of them for testing purpose ?

Comment: How do you check that amount the player receives increases? The `HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded` method only shows the current amount the player has

Comment: And probably because of `+=`. Each time you increase the coin by 200 with the line `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("coin", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coin") + 200);` And you add that value each time `r.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;` . Like first reward is 200. 0+200 = 200. Second reward is 400 in your case. 200+400 = 600 and so on.

Comment: Yes, one of them is for testing purpose. When i deploy to the phone to see the outcome i see that it increases.
I also think that it is because of  += because function itself is working properly when working outside of hanlder. What should i do? @EmreE

Comment: I am not sure, can think of 2 reasons rn, so try them both. First remove the `+=` and make it `=`. So like `r.OnAdRewarded = HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;`. If this not works, try changing `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("coin", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coin") );` to this, remove the `+200`. Cannot debug on my current pc atm. For removing the `+200` you need to initialize the first value at somewhere to 200.

Comment: OMG i found the solution, all i had to do is to put rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded; in Start() instead of putting into function! Thanks for replies!

Answer (score 0):

adding and creating new objects is the answer, 
for example the Void would have something like that

```
 public void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward args)
    {
        int CoinOld = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coin");
        CoinOld += 200;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("coin", CoinOld);
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Coin").GetComponent<Text>().text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coin").ToString();
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Double").GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;

        Debug.Log("Pref: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coin"));
    }
```